# How to show a child div without changing the position of that element's siblings?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div html tag from a login form, with a div inside that form that shows an error. The error div is at the top of the parent div. When the error is triggered, I want the error div to be inside the form div, without the form going down, but that is not what happens. I've already used `position: absolute` in the child div, but it stays in the left corner of the parent div. I've also used `z-index` too, so that the child div is over the parent div, but the parent always descends a pixel height the size of the child div. Let me show you the example:

```
<div id='formulario'  style={{height: 400px}}>
    {this.props.auth.error && <div id='erro'  style={{height:'15px'}}>Nao foi possivel fazer o login!</div>}
    <div id='login'>
    ...
   </div>
</div>
```

When `this.props.auth.error` is true, the error appears and the form id size becomes 415px. How do I leave the `#formulatrio` div with the size of `400px` and the `#login` div in place when the error appears?

Comment: you can use position: absolute in your styling

Comment: You want position: relative. See: [position | mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: @zfrish @BMcV , I already did the test with `position: absulute`, it works, but the div is the size of the error text, in the top, `position: 0` and `left: 0`. I need the error text to be in the middle of the parent div and the top part, like `top: 0` and `left: 50%`. But placing `id: error {position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0}`, the text starts from the middle of the div, but I need half of the error text to be exactly in the middle of the div. Something like `left: 48%` would do that, but it's not accurate.

Comment: is the `#erro` just supposed to show up centered, on top of the form? I'm unclear on your intent still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase the top CSS property to move the login div down to a certain position, 
added background for visualization.

```js
class MaintainPosition extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        id="formulario"
        style={{ height: "400px", backgroundColor: "lightblue" }}
      >
        {this.props.auth.error && (
          <div id="erro" style={{ height: "15px", color: "red" }}>
            Nao foi possivel fazer o login!
          </div>
        )}
        <div id="login">
            scroll down to toggle error
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: true
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MaintainPosition auth={{ error: this.state.error }} />
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ error: !this.state.error })}>
          toggle error
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
#err {
  
}

#formulario {
  position: relative;
}

#login {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#root {text-align: center}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


 <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Try to add a brief when answering. The code itself might be self-explanatory. However some wording prior the solution will reinforce intend.

Comment: @answered is not working ... when the div of the error text appears, it pushes the div with id: login pair below ... something like `z-index: 0` for `id = 'formulario'`, `z-index: 1` for `id = 'login'` and `z-index: 2` for `id = 'error'` also does not work ... the only thing that works is to put the `id = 'error'` with `position: absolute`, but it is not in the middle of the div. I need it to be exactly in the middle of the parent div.

Comment: @Joe I'm impressed with you, congratulations even for the answer, you're the guy ... I did not even say that the question was in react and you did everything ... again, congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for you to test I added the background.

```
<style>
    #formulario {
        display: grid;
        align-content: center;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: grey;
    }
    #erro {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 15px;
        background: yellow;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div id='formulario'>
    {this.props.auth.error && <div id='erro'>Nao foi possivel fazer o login!</div>}
    <div id='login'>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i need that div with id = 'login' not be pushed down the screen when the div with id = 'error' appears.

Comment: I believe it doesn't, don't you have anything else pushing it down?

Comment: I thought about leaving the div as a display: none, and when the error occurs it will display: visible, but the problem is that this div will always stay in the html, and I need it to exit when it is not being used

Comment: you can always remove it from the DOM using a little javascript like document.getElementById('formulário').removeChild(document.getElementById('erro'));  , but that was not your question :-)

Comment: @DeborahLuperini view my updated css, make your formulário display as grid and align-content:center, it will make your erro exactly in the middle of your formulário div

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Key here is to set the parent to `relative` so the child knows what to use a reference.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#erro').toggle();
});
```

```css
#formulario {
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  position: relative;
}

#erro {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Show/Hide Error</button>

<hr>

<div id='formulario' style='height: 400px'>
    <div id='erro' style='height: 15px'>Nao foi possivel fazer o login!</div>
    <div id='login'>
      Some<br/>
      Login<br/>
      Stuff<br/>
   </div>
</div>
```